# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working with multiple JSON objects where they are converted to nested dictionaries in which the last dictionary is extracted (as shown in "Data" segment). I want to extract all values of "Tags" into a list. WHile I'm trying to do this, I'm getting the output followed by an error.

Code:

```
import json

with open('console_data.json', 'r') as console_data:
    parsed_data = console_data.read()
    nodes = json.loads(parsed_data)

last_node = nodes[-1]                   # extract last dictionary

print("\n\n\n")
for item in last_node:
    tags = last_node[item].get("Tags", {})
    try:
        print(tags)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Data:

```
  {
    "Node": {
      "ID": "1a2b78dc-078d-cfe2-6c55-189aa2c67d29",
      "Node": "NAVIAPP05",
      "Address": "10.2.2.5",
      "Datacenter": "naviprod",
      "TaggedAddresses": {
        "lan": "10.2.2.5",
        "wan": "10.2.2.5"
      },
      "Meta": {
        "consul-network-segment": ""
      },
      "CreateIndex": 5171424,
      "ModifyIndex": 5453151
    },
    "Service": {
      "ID": "sim-work102235-10185",
      "Service": "sim",
      "Tags": [
        "fc216ed1-ef55-4064-b25d-de37ac612984",
        "2a82837f-1867-4b59-ab21-72331b75f4c2",
        "732b3fc1-687b-42ac-b71f-d755fe90de04",
        "d85d8902-8c36-4591-8f39-b4d8528301ce",
        "d5d695a6-710f-4edc-ae03-47ee034137a4",
        "62002f4a-4029-4f4f-a9d0-6b0fc2f34951",
        "459cc8e3-fc44-43ce-9d7f-dfa3fe92665e"
      ],
      "Address": "10.2.2.35",
      "Meta": {
        "apiContext": "/sim/sim.do",
        "defaultContext": "/sim",
        "workflowContext": "/sim/services",
        "zspContext": "/sim/services",
        "zspProductURL": "https://sim.abcde.com/sim/"
      },
      "Port": 10185,
      "EnableTagOverride": false,
      "CreateIndex": 7327367,
      "ModifyIndex": 7327367
    },
    "Checks": [
      {
        "Node": "NAVIAPP05",
        "CheckID": "serfHealth",
        "Name": "Serf Health Status",
        "Status": "passing",
        "Notes": "",
        "Output": "Agent alive and reachable",
        "ServiceID": "",
        "ServiceName": "",
        "ServiceTags": [],
        "Definition": {},
        "CreateIndex": 5171424,
        "ModifyIndex": 5171424
      }
    ]
  }
```

Output:

```
{}
['fc216ed1-ef55-4064-b25d-de37ac612984', '2a82837f-1867-4b59-ab21-72331b75f4c2', '732b3fc1-687b-42ac-b71f-d755fe90de04', 'd85d8902-8c36-4591-8f39-b4d8528301ce', 'd5d695a6-710f-4edc-ae03-47ee034137a4', '62002f4a-4029-4f4f-a9d0-6b0fc2f34951', '459cc8e3-fc44-43ce-9d7f-dfa3fe92665e']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_parse_json.py", line 12, in <module>
    tags = last_dict[item].get("Tags", {})
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Expected Output:

```
['fc216ed1-ef55-4064-b25d-de37ac612984', '2a82837f-1867-4b59-ab21-72331b75f4c2', '732b3fc1-687b-42ac-b71f-d755fe90de04', 'd85d8902-8c36-4591-8f39-b4d8528301ce', 'd5d695a6-710f-4edc-ae03-47ee034137a4', '62002f4a-4029-4f4f-a9d0-6b0fc2f34951', '459cc8e3-fc44-43ce-9d7f-dfa3fe92665e']
```

Comment: I've had a look at related questions, but unable to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Data you enclosed is from `last_node`, why not just use:

`last_node['Service']['Tags']`

This outputs:

```
['fc216ed1-ef55-4064-b25d-de37ac612984',
 '2a82837f-1867-4b59-ab21-72331b75f4c2',
 '732b3fc1-687b-42ac-b71f-d755fe90de04',
 'd85d8902-8c36-4591-8f39-b4d8528301ce',
 'd5d695a6-710f-4edc-ae03-47ee034137a4',
 '62002f4a-4029-4f4f-a9d0-6b0fc2f34951',
 '459cc8e3-fc44-43ce-9d7f-dfa3fe92665e']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in your `console_data.json`. This code works on `Data` above.

```py
import json
with open('Data.json','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    nodes = json.loads(data)

tags = nodes['Service']['Tags']
print(tags)
```